# Parameterizing Spring @Scheduled with default value

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I need to parameterize a `@Scheduled` method with value from my properties file if present, or default value if not.

We can parameterize from configuration file property in the following way:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${my.task.cron-exec-expr}")
public void scheduledTask() {
    // do something
}
```

but if the property does not exist we'll have a runtime exception.

I've tried using a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean with default value, with no success:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.task")
public class MyTaskProperties {

    private String cronExecExpr = "*/5 * * * * *";

    // getter and setter
}
```

How to avoid that and pass a default value?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add the default value in the placeholder like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${my.task.cron-exec-expr:*/5 * * * * *}")
```